# Horizontal scroll navbar at bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a navbar with a horizontal scroll at the bottom of the page, but when I put `position: fixed;` it makes the navbar not scrollable.

```css
div.scrollmenu {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div.scrollmenu a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

div.scrollmenu a:hover {
  background-color: #777;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollmenu">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#support">Support</a>
  <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
  <a href="#tools">Tools</a>  
  <a href="#base">Base</a>
  <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
  <a href="#more">More</a>
  <a href="#logo">Logo</a>
  <a href="#friends">Friends</a>
  <a href="#partners">Partners</a>
  <a href="#people">People</a>
  <a href="#work">Work</a>
</div>

<h2>Horizontal Scrollable Menu</h2>
```

here the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/J1aaa/rco4kz70/3/

Comment: Can you specify exactly what you want? Is the menu position fixed?

Comment: I want the menu to be placed at the bottom of the page, and it can scroll horizontally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your element with a wrapper div - and that is what is is fixed to the bottom and extends across the entire viewport. That way its not the overflowing element that is fixed - its the wrapping div and the existing structure will overflow horizontally as intended.

```css
.scroll-menu-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0; 
  right: 0;
}

.scrollmenu {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div.scrollmenu a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

div.scrollmenu a:hover {
  background-color: #777;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-menu-wrapper">
  <div class="scrollmenu">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#support">Support</a>
    <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
    <a href="#tools">Tools</a>  
    <a href="#base">Base</a>
    <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
    <a href="#more">More</a>
    <a href="#logo">Logo</a>
    <a href="#friends">Friends</a>
    <a href="#partners">Partners</a>
    <a href="#people">People</a>
    <a href="#work">Work</a>
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Horizontal Scrollable Menu</h2>
```

Comment: thank you for trying to help me, it work perfectly

Comment: You are welcome - glad I could help - happy coding :)

Answer (score 4):

all you have to do is "width" and "overflow-x "scroll shape

```
div.scrollmenu width: 100%; and overflow-x: auto;
```

```css
div.scrollmenu {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
}

div.scrollmenu a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

div.scrollmenu a:hover {
  background-color: #777;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollmenu">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#support">Support</a>
  <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
  <a href="#tools">Tools</a>  
  <a href="#base">Base</a>
  <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
  <a href="#more">More</a>
  <a href="#logo">Logo</a>
  <a href="#friends">Friends</a>
  <a href="#partners">Partners</a>
  <a href="#people">People</a>
  <a href="#work">Work</a>
</div>

<h2>Horizontal Scrollable Menu</h2>
```

Comment: thanks, it works, but you need to put `left: 0;right: 0;` to make it pefectly at the bottom.

Comment: I just tried to solve your problem. Right and left of course must be 0